# SQLite database questions, problems with design (indexing/multiple fields)

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, database-normalization

I use stackoverflow a lot, but this is my first question here, so if i'm doing anything wrong just let me know. I'm not a programmer (I just do programming for my own needs) so I'm open to tutorial suggestions etc. I won't be offended if you just give me something to read and find the answers myself.

OK, to the point - I'm trying to write simple application to track my personal expenses and I have a problem with database design. I'm using VStudio to create the database (SQLite). I attached a diagram with my design and I have some questions.

[My SQLite diagram](http://i59.tinypic.com/21nfybq.jpg)

I don't know exactly how to design "Transactions" table. Fields like Date, Payment Type etc. seems to be easy enough but the idea was to store in this table information about transactions so I need to store multiple products there. I've read about it and created table "Transactions_Products" that will help with that. My problem is : where do I put quantity of products in the transaction? I can't think of a place to put it. I tried to find similar databases but couldn't find anything.

Second thing. I've read about indexing a lot, but I still can't grasp the idea. I don't know when to use it. Should I use it only on fields that I will be "querying" a lot?

Last one - is it better for such a small application just for myself to store my account balance in a separate table or should I just calculate it every time?

As I said, I don't need answers like: "do this, do that". If you just give me some good tutorials/articles I think I can find answers on my own, but I couldn't find it. Maybe I'm searching for it wrong.

Thank you in advance for any information.

Comment: Is it possible to have the diagram shown inline?

Comment: Read [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: @CL. thank you Sir, I'll read that for sure!

Comment: @CoryRoy I'm sorry Sir, but I don't understand what "inline" means. Do you mean SQL preview of the tables? Or posting picture directly here?

Comment: @Monastario It means use the image icon when composing your question instead of the link icon.

Comment: @CoryRoy so yeah, posting picture directly, of course I would post like this but unfortunately I can't do that yet (10 posts I think)

Comment: @Monastario Oh, I forgot that was a limitation in new accounts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where do I put quantity of products in the transaction?

Transactions is a bad table name as it's vague and has multiple meanings. Consider "payments", "purchase invoices", etc. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831 for some existing patterns.

> Should I use [indexes] only on fields that I will be "querying" a lot?

There's no free lunch. Indexes take space, and can slow down inserts. Start with indexes on your primary keys (which is the default for SQLite), measure what is slow (looking at query plans) and add indexes if they help and if you have room.

> is it better for such a small application just for myself to store my account balance in a separate table or should I just calculate it every time?

For an operational/transactional database like you describe, avoid storing calculated values. SQLite can count numbers quickly :)

Premature optimization is premature. Make it work first with full normalization. If you have performance problems, analyze what is really causing the slow-down and go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it and see if I'll be able to solve my problems :) I'll also read some more about normalization.